# What is a quick way to get a linear combination of two large arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays A and B of dimension (87256 X 87256).

I have a single factor alpha which I keep changing.

I am trying to find the fastest way of getting:

alpha * A + (1 - alpha) * B

Using simple numpy, it takes around 4 min 8 s to calculate.

What is the quickest way of calculating this array? I have a multi-core system, so parallel computing is not a limitation.

Comment: If you know all your alpha values in advance you can vectorize that bit too. But it's probably still going to take a long time...

Comment: You might be hampered by memory issues as well. Array A has about 7.6 billion entries. Assuming these entries are 4 byte floats A will require about 30 GB of storage. So will B. So will the resulting array. If you don’t gave more than 90 GBs of RAM in your system the OS will have to page some portions of these arrays to disk, regardless of parallelization of the computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two options:

### Option-A

```py
# multiplying only once
C = B + alpha*(A-B)
```

### Option-B

I expanded on @Massifox's answer.

```py
import numba
import numpy as np

def get_result(A, B, alpha = 0.5):
    return B + alpha*(A-B)

get_result_jit = numba.vectorize(['float64(float64, float64, float64)'])(get_result)
```

### Other resources:

1. [Numba tutorial](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.12/tutorial_numpy_and_numba.html)
2. See decorators for: [`@numba.vectorize`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.12/tutorial_numpy_and_numba.html#the-vectorize-decorator), [`@numba.guvectorize`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.12/tutorial_numpy_and_numba.html#the-guvectorize-decorator) and [`@numba.jit` and `@numba.njit`](https://towardsdatascience.com/speed-up-your-algorithms-part-2-numba-293e554c5cc1).
3. [**Speeding up algorithms with Numba**](https://towardsdatascience.com/speed-up-your-algorithms-part-2-numba-293e554c5cc1)

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch to [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) changing very few lines of code put the turbo on your Numpy: parallelizing your code by taking full advantage of the CPU multicores and / or GPU cores.

Numba is an open source JIT compiler that translates a subset of Python and NumPy code into fast machine code.